# How do I turn my .asm code to an usable .exe file?

Tags: assembly, exe

I am learning coding right now, (specifically Assembly 8086,and running it in DosBox emulator), and I made a game that includes a couple of .asm files... i would like to publish this game in a tiny site where all my friends publish their games too, but for that i need to make the file a downloadable .exe file... as I said, I am using the Dosbox 8086 Emulator and TASM/BIN... Any help would be amazing... 
Thanks ahead,
Gambizon

I have searched many of these forums, and could not understand, what I should do...

Comment: You can upload source and small binaries to e.g. github.

Answer (score 0):

Most assemblers convert the source text (stored in file(s) `*.asm`) to so called *object code* `*.obj` which is not directly executable. You need a linker to convert the object file into `*.exe`. Borland provides `TLINK.exe`. 
Makefile of your game might look like this:

```
  TASM /z /zi Game.asm
  TLINK /v Game.obj
```

You can run it as 
    `Game.exe` or better using Turbo Debugger as
    `TD.exe Game.exe`.

Or you may prefer assemblers which convert `*.asm` directly to executables. See an example [euroassembler.eu/prodos16/tdosapi.htm](https://euroassembler.eu/prodos16/tdosapi.htm)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer, I tried to enter the link you gave me but I was pretty lost on the site... Could you pleaseguide me to where i can convert my files?

Comment: As your sources are written in TASM, you should get TLINK.exe at the same place where you downloaded TASM.exe. 
A link to Borland tools is also available at https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/links.htm#TASM

Comment: Just so I can make sure, Because some of my teachers told me it is possible and some told me it wasn't, can I , as for an example, send this .exe file to a game publishing site like itch.io as a .exe file, and make it work without dosbox?